# How can I fix the initial delay on this infinite-rotator animation loop?

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet of code to essentially infinitely loop through a group of images and fade in and out from one to another. I have 11 images in total, each with the class of 'logo'.

I have variables set to control the durations of the animations and delays, although on the load of the first image, it delays for a while and then proceeds to loop through the rest of the images as it should, then repeats.

I need the animation to start firing right away, without a 5 - 10 second delay.
Its not load issues. I've already determined that.

It seems to me that its almost as if its not triggering the animations for the first cycle through the loop. Or in other words, it looks like to me the initial delay before animation is the duration of itemInterval var times the number of items being looped through. Again 11 items, so roughly about a 10 second delay before the animation starts when itemInterval is set at 1500.

What is causing this and how can I fix it? Thank you!

**EDIT:** The initialFadeIn does not affect this what-ever, Ive set it from 1ms to 10000ms without any change in behavior.

```
function front_rotator() {
  //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
  var initialFadeIn = 500;
  //interval between items (in milliseconds)
  var itemInterval = 1500;
  //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
  var fadeTime = 600;
  //count number of items
  var numberOfItems = $('.logo').length;
  //set current item
  var currentItem = 0;
  //show first item
  $('.logo').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);
  //loop through the items
  var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function () {
      $('.logo').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);
      if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
          currentItem = 0;
      } else {
          currentItem++;
      }
      $('.logo').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);
  }, itemInterval);
}
front_rotator();
```

**I FIGURED OUT HOW TO WRITE A CORRECTLY FUNCTIONING INFINITE LOOP USING VANILLA JS**

thanks for the help tho guys. :)

Comment: Just notice your logical, the first currentItem =1 , then first will fadeOut 1 and fadeIn 2,  then in next loop will start with currentItem=0

Comment: whoops, good catch. that is actually something i tested, it seems it slipped past me to change it back to 0, my apologies. still the same result happens whether that var is set to 0 or 1.

Comment: perhaps more concise: `currentItem = (currentItem + 1) % numberOfItems`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
// initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
var initialFadeIn = 500;
// interval between items (in milliseconds)
var itemInterval = 1500;
// cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
var fadeTime = 600;
// cache items
var items = $('.logo');
// count number of items
var numberOfItems = items.length;
// set current item
var currentItem = 0;
// helper function for animation
var fader = function(current){
  items.eq(current).fadeOut(fadeTime);

  if (current == numberOfItems - 1) {
    currentItem = 0;
  } else {
    currentItem++;
  }

  items.eq(current).fadeIn(fadeTime);
}

function front_rotator() {
  // fade the first
  fader(currentItem);
  //loop through the items
  var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function () {
    // fade the rest
    fader(currentItem);
  }, itemInterval);
}

front_rotator();
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKvWMj)

The animation isn't starting right away since it's dependent on the setInterval delay. I moved your animation logic into a helper function that is invoked on start and during each interval loop.

Comment: this didnt run correctly with the elements i have, it provided with random fades to random images. sorry :(

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're working with so we don't have to guess what the markup is or how you've structured things?

Comment: yeah sorry im still figuring out what all is necessary. Its just a div with image tags inside it, each has a class of logo, and current item also has a class of current-logo.

Comment: css is just position absolute to stack them. i figured this out in vanilla js. ill probably post to github if interested.

Comment: http://www.techtronixweb.com/rabbitWerks/infinite-looper/index.html

https://github.com/Sharpie360/infinite-looper